# Compare 2 dataframes within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As a part of data comparison project. i have 2 DF's which  i had merged

df1:

A   B   C

a1  t8  u7

d5  g6  e5

c3  s3  s6

df2:

A   B   C

q8  e6  d3

g4  s1  d0

s2  w3  r3

Merged dataframe df3

A   B   C   A   B   C

a1  t8  u7  q8  e6  d3

d5  g6  e5  g4  s1  d0

c3  s3  s6  s2  w3  r3

and want to compare them in a side by side along with new  column as "difference"

A   A   Difference  B   B   Difference  C   C   Difference

a1  q8   FALSE      t8  e6   FALSE     u7   d3   FALSE

d5  g4   FALSE      g6  s1   FALSE     e5   d0   FALSE

c3  s2   FALSE      s3  w3   FALSE     s6   r3   FALSE

Please assist in comparing the values in df3 in above format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in pandas is the best avoid duplicated columns names, so suggest this solution:

- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) both `DataFrames` with boolean `df`, use parameter `keys` for `MultiIndex`
- sort by second level of columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)
- if necessary `MultiIndex` is flattening by `map`

---

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df1 == df2], axis=1, keys=('a','b', 'diff'))
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)

  a_A b_A  diff_A a_B b_B  diff_B a_C b_C  diff_C
0  a1  q8   False  t8  e6   False  u7  d3   False
1  d5  g4   False  g6  s1   False  e5  d0   False
2  c3  s2   False  s3  w3   False  s6  r3   False
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting the below error   ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: It means both dataframes are different. What is `print(df1.info())` and `print(df2.info())` ?

Comment: DF1: dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(10), int64(5), object(6)                DF2: dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(15), object(6)

Comment: @AbhishekGupta - You need same columns names, what return `print ((df1.index == df2.index).all())` and `print ((df1.columns == df2.columns).all())` ? Both has to be True.

Comment: Below are the results                            print ((df3.index == df4.index).all()) 

False

print ((df4.columns == df4.columns).all())
                                                                                                              True

Comment: @AbhishekGupta - It means there is different number of rows?

Comment: Yes both data frames are having different number of rows. Is there a way to share the full code with you.

Comment: Also i had used df2 = df2.reindex(index=df1.index). will this piece of code not gonna address the mismatch in row issues

Comment: hmmm, `df2 = df2.reindex(index=df1.index)` does not work? Can you explain more `not gonna address the mismatch ` ?

Comment: Means DF1 is having 250 rows and DF2 is having 230 rows.

Comment: do you think after `df2 = df2.reindex(index=df1.index)` ?

Comment: yes. i believe so as after running the code i can now see the number of rows in DF2are now matching with DF1                                                            df2.shape
Out[8]: (249, 23)

df1.shape
Out[9]: (249, 23)

Comment: but it is not. Is there a way to share the entire code with you

Comment: @AbhishekGupta - Yes, please send me your data if not confidental with your code to my email from my profile.